# How to use private frameworks in Xcode for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How do I use private frameworks in Xcode 4.1 for iOS 4.0 or later? Tutorials or articles would be useful.

Comment: This is a legitimate question, but it would be better if:

1. You told us what you want the private APIs for - we may be able to suggest a workaround.

2. You did a little more research. http://ericasadun.com and this github repo should have all you need: https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: You don't.

If you plan on going through the App Store approval process at all, then you might do some careful object graph navigation and stuff and hope that Apple doesn't care too much about what you do.

If on the other hand you're thinking about working with jailbroken devices, then that might be a valid question, but you better say so, otherwise it's not clear.

Comment: Well.. you can also use them for apps for enterprise deployment.